# Grails GORM beforeUpdate method not invoked

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to fix an issue with my application where the `beforeUpdate` method in one of my domain classes is not invoked.

If none of the fields *belonging directly to the domain class* are updated, then the `beforeUpdate` event isn't fired. I guess this makes sense, however I would like the code in my `beforeUpdate` method to execute even in cases where only associations of my domain class are updated.

For instance, my domain class looks something like this:

```
class Organisation {
    String name
    Location location

    def beforeUpdate() {
        //do some stuff with the location when it's updated
    }
}
```

If the parameters map submitted from the form contains the `name` parameter, then `beforeUpdate` is fired. If the parameters map only contains `location` parameters, then it is not.

Is there any way to make Grails fire `beforeUpdate` even if I'm only updating associations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your question is:

`beforeUpdate` will not fire unless one of the values of the properties on the domain class has changed.

In your case `beforeUpdate` is not being called because no property of `Organisation` has changed.

The only thing I can think to do in this situation is to change your domain model to allow `Location` to be aware of it's owning `Organisation` and manually call `beforeUpdate` from within the `Location`'s `beforeUpdate`. All though, this feels hacky and smells bad.

Comment: You're right - and that's a good suggestion for a dirty hack, although it doesn't work if `location` is initially null.

Answer (score 2):

The `beforeUpdate` method is only fired when the object is actually updated, what you're probably seeing is that when only one parameter is submitted your domain instance is in an invalid state and doesn't validate, hence is never updated. What you are probably looking for to solve your case is the `beforeValidate` method.